# arrange rows of one file same as rows in second

Tags: linux, perl, bash, sed, awk

I have two files and i want to arrange rows of 2nd file in the same order of rows in 1st file. where column no 2 and 5 of 2nd files have same values as 1st file only the difference is their order is different. considering that complete rows should rearrange not only 2nd and 3rd columns . please suggest.

```
$ cat file1
FEX
MRU
MOV
FTL
MOY
$ cat file2
1/24/2013,MOV,144523,1/25/2013,MOV,1445231
1/24/2013,MOY,298792,1/25/2013,MOY,2987921
1/24/2013,FEX,628037,1/25/2013,FEX,6280371
1/24/2013,MRU,146084,1/25/2013,MRU,1460841
1/24/2013,FTL,454709,1/25/2013,FTL,4547091
```

Required output:

```
1/24/2013,FEX,628037,1/25/2013,FEX,6280371
1/24/2013,MRU,146084,1/25/2013,MRU,1460841
1/24/2013,MOV,144523,1/25/2013,MOV,1445231
1/24/2013,FTL,454709,1/25/2013,FTL,4547091
1/24/2013,MOY,298792,1/25/2013,MOY,2987921
```

Comment: Can you guarantee that you key file contains unique keys? Whilst I'm at it, can you guarantee that they key should always exist (at some point file2 data was the the "source" of file1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming fields 2 and 5 are always the same, here's one way using `awk`:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR { a[$2]=$0; next } { print a[$0] }' file2 file1
```

Results:

```
1/24/2013,FEX,628037,1/25/2013,FEX,6280371
1/24/2013,MRU,146084,1/25/2013,MRU,1460841
1/24/2013,MOV,144523,1/25/2013,MOV,1445231
1/24/2013,FTL,454709,1/25/2013,FTL,4547091
1/24/2013,MOY,298792,1/25/2013,MOY,2987921
```